# Is it possible to update image texture by using image buffer pointer?

Tags: python, image

I want to know if it is possible to pass `bpy.data.images["image"].as_pointer()` to a C function to update image pixels directly, instead of using `pixels.foreach_set()` and `pixels.foreach_get()`

Edit:

I tried the following to change the float_buffer,but this did not work, the image stays the same. I have tried updating the image by setting the dirty flag, but this results in illegal memory access crash. I also tried calling image.update() and image.pixels.update() on the Python side hoping for a miracle lol.

```
void EXPORT set_all_pixels_to_white(ImBuf *buf) {
    float *pixels = buf->float_buffer.data;
    int num_pixels = buf->x * buf->y * buf->channels;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pixels; i += buf->channels) {
        pixels[i] = 1;
        pixels[i + 1] = 0;
        pixels[i + 2] = 0;
        pixels[i + 3] = 1;
    }
}
```

Python side:

```
scene.mydll.set_all_pixels_to_red.argtypes = [POINTER(c_uint8)]
scene.mydll.set_all_pixels_to_red(byref(ctypes.c_uint8(my_image.as_pointer())))
```

Answer (score 2):

From the source code that [Blender Python uses to set image pixels](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/773d5745e86c2edc8907e66ea93ff3906855fb5b/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_image.cc#L632), we can learn a thing or two:

- The pointer you are sending to the dll refers to an `Image`. That is a different type than `ImBuf`.
- You can get the `ImBuf` using `BKE_image_acquire_ibuf()`, so you have to mimic that function somehow in your dll.
- An `ImBuf` is not *always* using the `float_buffer`. When `ibuf->float_buffer.data == nullptr`, it means that the image data is in `ibuf->byte_buffer.data`.
- It is not guaranteed that an image has 4 channels, that's only when the image has an alpha channel. So to be completely safe when writing the pixel data, you should do something like

```
if (buf->channels == 4) {
  pixels[i + 3] = 1;
}
```

Perhaps this gives you some directions to get your code working.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. I missed `BKE_image_acquire_ibuf()` during my search of Blender source code.